# How to make mocha let my program write files?

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

I have a very strange behaviour (from my point of view):

I cannot write any file when I make my unit tests using mocha (I can create the files but nothing is written to them).

As an example I have this piece of code:

```
    console.log('The beginning');
    var fs = require('fs');

    var writableStream = fs.createWriteStream("./testOuputFile.txt");

    function callback(s){
        console.log('callback', s);
    }

    writableStream.on("error", function(err) {
        console.log("ERROR");
        done(err);
    });
    writableStream.on("close", function(ex) {
        console.log("CLOSED");
        done();
    });
    writableStream.on("finish", function(ex) {
        console.log("ENDED");
        done();
    });
    writableStream.on("open", function(fd) {
        console.log("OPENED:"+fd);
    });
    if(typeof callback === "undefined"){
        callback = function(s){console.log(s);};
    }
    var cbCalled = false;
    function done(err) {
        if (!cbCalled) {
            callback(err);
            cbCalled = true;
        }
    }
    writableStream.write('Something');
    writableStream.end();

    fs.writeFile('message.txt', 'Hello Node', function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('It\'s saved!');
    });

    console.log('The end');
```

Copying this code into a file named run.js and run 'node run.js' will output:

```
    The beginning
    The end
    OPENED:11
    ENDED
    callback undefined
    CLOSED
    It's saved!
```

I obtain two nice files containing some text: testOutputFile.txt and message.txt

Doing the same into a file named test/test.js and run 'mocha' will output:

```
    The beginning
    The end



        0 tests complete (0 ms)
```

And I obtain two empty files (zero bytes): testOutputFile.txt and message.txt

Is it normal ?

Is there something to tune in mocha to make this work ?

Comment: Where is the actual test? Can you show us the `it` and `describe` parts?

Comment: Is it linked with this ? Actually, my real-life mocha file is 600 lines long, and I already wrote a file from mocha in another program without this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost certainly you forgot to include the `done` callback in your describe/it function argument list so mocha thinks your test is synchronous and it doesn't have any way to know when your IO is done, so as soon as your function returns, mocha ends the process. But as @BenjaminGruenbaum points out, you omitted the interesting part of the code, so post the full code and we'll confirm.

Comment: This is most likely the issue, your it statement must be in the form `it("description here",function(done){`

Comment: Great, the problem came from this. This asynchronous way of programming is really a pain to me: I already had done this, but did not think that could also avoid prevent file from being written.

Comment: To be clear, it's not like mocha is magically preventing the file from being written, mocha is doing a `process.exit()` and any pending IO operations are aborted. As I understand it, node probably doesn't even have a chance to issue those IO calls to the OS before the process ends.

Comment: Thanks Peter, I agree that is the explanation to my problem.

Comment: The fix for me was to put wstream.close() inside the callback of `wstream.write('data', (e) => { wstream.close(); callback(e); }`. This allowed node to actually flush the write before mocha died.