# Writing JSON data to a file using Node FileSystem fs.writeFileSync()

Tags: node.js, fs

I'm a Javascript newcomer and am trying to write some test data in JSON format using Nodes 'fs' module.

The file writing should be done at the end of some Mocha tests:

```
after(() => {
        console.log(customer.urn);
        fs.writeFileSync('testData.json', JSON.stringify(customer.urn));
});
```

`testData.json` lives in the same directory as the test script as an already existing blank .json file.

The `console.log(...` prints the customer urn but nothing gets written to the data file - I'm sure it's something very simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using the done callback in the after function argument list.
Hence `mocha` thinks your test is synchronous and it does not have any way to know whether your IO completed or not.
As soon as your function returns mocha ends the node process and the IO was not sent to the OS.

Please try this and it should work

```
after((done) => {
    console.log(customer.urn);
    fs.writeFileSync('testData.json', JSON.stringify(customer.urn));
    done();
});
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16840404/how-to-make-mocha-let-my-program-write-files  you could cite the source...